# Pass variable to join query in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

There is a similar problem like this but instead, his problem was passing the ID. But mine is something else. Like this. But I get errors.

```
$this->db->join($user_role, $user_role.'school_id = user.school_id', 'left');
```

Gives `Unknown column 'adminschool_id' in 'on clause'`

```
$this->db->join($user_role, $user_role'.school_id = user.school_id', 'left');
```

Gives `unexpected ''.school_id = user.school_id''`

Comment: what is value for variable $user_role ?

Comment: It holds admin,student,teacher.

Comment: one value at a time, correct ? and when you get error : unexpected ''.school_id = user.school_id'' , it means at that at that time $user_role variable value is empty and because of it its gives you error. you can also try by passing fourth parameter to your join as below :
$this->db->join($user_role, $user_role'.school_id = user.school_id', 'left',FALSE);

Comment: I already fixed this though. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer. I'll just answer my own question to help others.

```
$this->db->join($user_role, $user_role.'.school_id = user.school_id', 'left');
```

Notice the `.'.` in `$variable.'.school_id..`